# Получение объекта с Retrofit RxJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava, rxandroid

Имеется метод `requestQuery(String query)` основная задача которого состоит в том, чтобы возвращать список объектов `List<QueryData>` после их загрузки Retrofitom. Объект Query имеет всего один параметр - String message

```
public static List<QueryData> requestQuery(final String query) {
    ApiStepik apiStepik = App.getApi();
    List<QueryData> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable<QueryResponse> queryDataObservable = App.getApi().getQuery(query);
    queryDataObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(data -> {
                for (QueryData q : data.getQueries())
                Log.d("TEXT", q.getText());
            });
    return result;
}
```

Получение данных в subscribe происходит нормально, лог печатается, однако если я пытаюсь вызвать метод в `onCreate()`, то получаю null. Можно ли как-то получать в onCreate List, или всю работу с данными придется делать в subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам придётся изменить основную задачу метода `requestQuery(String query)`. Проблема в том, что этот метод скорее всего у вас вызывается в коде, где всё работает синхронно, а выполнение запроса и возврат результатов - асинхронная задача.

Поэтому всё же придётся делать что-то вроде:

```
public static void requestQuery(final String query) {
   App.getApi().getQuery(query)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(data -> {
         // вывод нужных данных в UI
      });
}
```